# Convert a dot seperated string into a JSON Object

Tags: java, json

So i have a dot seperated string which i am trying to convert into a JSON Object in JAVA. The structure is as follows.

```
Person.City.FirstNm.LastNm=xyz, Person.City.Address=abc. Person.City.firstNm.Salary=1000.24, Person.State.FirstNm.LastNm=xyz
```

and so on. The resulting JSON should be something like this. Note there can be a decimal point in the value.

```
{
    Person:
    {
        City:
        {
            firstNm:
            {
                LastNm:xyz,
                        Salary:1000.24
            },
            Address: abc
        },
        State:
        {
            FirstNm:
            {
                LastNm:xyz
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to make a Map from the string and then use it to make a JSON string which i can use to make it as an Object but no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please upload the problematic code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to build tree-like structure for storing objects. Than, just `toString()` it. Below is how I see you can do it:

```
public class TestJson {
    static abstract class Node {
    }

    static class IntermediateNode extends Node {
        public Map<String, Node> keyValueMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("{");
            sb.append(keyValueMap.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue())
                       .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));

            sb.append("}");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }


    static class LeafNode extends Node {
        public String value;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testString =
                "Person.City.FirstNm.LastNm=xyz, Person.City.Address=abc, Person.City.FirstNm.Salary=1000.24, Person"
                + ".State.FirstNm.LastNm=xyz";

        IntermediateNode root = new IntermediateNode();
        for (String param : testString.replaceAll(" ", "").split(",")) {
            String[] def = param.split("=");

            String[] result = def[0].split("\\.");
            IntermediateNode currentNode = root;
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i++) {
                Node node = currentNode.keyValueMap.get(result[i]);
                if (node == null) {
                    IntermediateNode child = new IntermediateNode();
                    currentNode.keyValueMap.put(result[i].trim(), child);
                    currentNode = child;
                } else {
                    currentNode = (IntermediateNode) node;
                }
            }
            LeafNode leaf = new LeafNode();
            leaf.value = def[1];
            currentNode.keyValueMap.put(result[result.length - 1], leaf);
        }

        System.out.println(root);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this solves it. Yaa i was not getting the DS. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hey its working fine for objects but How can we represent the array?