# How to map a key-value structure with composite key to json object in Java

Tags: java, json, database, gson

I have a database keeping key-value objects. A key maybe composite with a separator, e.g. `stackoverflow.questions.ask`. I want to map such object to JSON. Thus, for `stackoverflow.questions.ask` key I want to get

```
{
    'stackoverflow' : {
        'questions' : {
                'ask' : 'value'
            }
        }
}
```

Is there any simple way to do it automatically?

Comment: I assume that `quitions`, `qustions` and `quiestions` all mean `question`... right?

Comment: Try to take a look at this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38020712/convert-a-dot-seperated-string-into-a-json-object) if I understand you right you are trying to achieve something similar as here.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you for the remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Gson is a right tool here, but I really like this question.
This is a general algorithm and you can implement it yourself and generalize it to support various scenarios.
Here is an example implementation, but since I'm weak at writing algorithms, it can give you an idea of reimplementing it in a  much better manner.

```java
final class Split {

    private Split() {
    }

    static <E, R, K, V> R split(final Iterator<E> iterator, final Splitter<E, R, K, V> splitter) {
        final R outerResult = splitter.newResult();
        while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
            final E e = iterator.next();
            doSplit(splitter, outerResult, e);
        }
        return outerResult;
    }

    static <E, R, K, V> R split(final Iterable<E> iterable, final Splitter<E, R, K, V> splitter) {
        final R outerResult = splitter.newResult();
        for ( final E e : iterable ) {
            doSplit(splitter, outerResult, e);
        }
        return outerResult;
    }

    static <E, R, K, V> Collector<E, ?, R> asCollector(final Splitter<E, R, K, V> splitter) {
        return Collector.of(
                splitter::newResult,
                (outerResult, e) -> doSplit(splitter, outerResult, e),
                (r1, r2) -> {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                },
                Function.identity()
        );
    }

    private static <E, R, K, V> void doSplit(final Splitter<E, R, K, V> splitter, final R outerResult, final E e) {
        final K elementKey = splitter.elementToKey(e);
        final K[] keyGroup = splitter.keyToKeyGroup(elementKey);
        R result = outerResult;
        final int lastI = keyGroup.length - 1;
        for ( int i = 0; i < lastI; i++ ) {
            final K innerKey = keyGroup[i];
            final R candidateInnerResult = splitter.fromInnerResult(result, innerKey);
            if ( candidateInnerResult == null ) {
                final R newTargetResult = splitter.newResult();
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final V castNewTargetResult = (V) newTargetResult;
                splitter.toInnerResult(result, innerKey, castNewTargetResult);
                result = newTargetResult;
            } else {
                result = candidateInnerResult;
            }
        }
        final V value = splitter.elementToValue(e);
        splitter.toInnerResult(result, keyGroup[lastI], value);
    }

}
```

In general, `doSplit(...)` tries to "split" keys for any sequence of elements, hence you can split anything, not just maps.

Here is the interface that is used above.
All of its methods are used in `doSplit(...)` to do different tasks.

```java
// E - type of elements it can process
// R - the result object type
// K - key type
// K - value type
interface Splitter<E, R, K, V> {

    // A factory method to create the outer of an inner result  
    R newResult();

    // A method to extract a key from the element
    K elementToKey(E element);

    // A method to extract a value from the element
    V elementToValue(E element);

    // A method to split a key to a key group so we can have a nested objects identitied with
    K[] keyToKeyGroup(K key);

    // A method to extract an inner result from existing inner result
    R fromInnerResult(R innerResult, K innerKey);

    // A method to put a key/value pair to the result
    void toInnerResult(R innerResult, K innerKey, V value);

    // A convenience method similar to Collector.of
    static <E, R, K, V> Splitter<E, R, K, V> of(
            final Function<? super E, ? extends K> elementToKey,
            final Function<? super E, ? extends V> elementToValue,
            final Function<? super K, ? extends K[]> keyToKeyGroup,
            final Supplier<? extends R> newResult,
            final BiFunction<? super R, ? super K, ? extends R> fromInnerResult,
            final TriConsumer<? super R, ? super K, ? super V> toInnerResult
    ) {
        return new Splitter<E, R, K, V>() {
            @Override
            public R newResult() {
                return newResult.get();
            }

            @Override
            public K elementToKey(final E element) {
                return elementToKey.apply(element);
            }

            @Override
            public V elementToValue(final E element) {
                return elementToValue.apply(element);
            }

            @Override
            public K[] keyToKeyGroup(final K key) {
                return keyToKeyGroup.apply(key);
            }

            @Override
            public R fromInnerResult(final R innerResult, final K innerKey) {
                return fromInnerResult.apply(innerResult, innerKey);
            }

            @Override
            public void toInnerResult(final R innerResult, final K innerKey, final V value) {
                toInnerResult.accept(innerResult, innerKey, value);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

And since there is no a tri-consumer in Java 8:

```java
interface TriConsumer<T, U, V> {

    void accept(T t, U u, V v);

}
```

Now, since this is a generic approach, you can have multiple implementations.
For example, a splitter that can split the sequence to a map:

```java
final class MapSplitters {

    private MapSplitters() {
    }

    static <K, V> Splitter<Map.Entry<K, V>, Map<K, V>, K, V> of(final Function<? super K, ? extends K[]> keyToKeyGroup) {
        return of(keyToKeyGroup, LinkedTreeMap::new);
    }

    static <K, V> Splitter<Map.Entry<K, V>, Map<K, V>, K, V> of(final Function<? super K, ? extends K[]> keyToKeyGroup,
            final Supplier<? extends Map<K, V>> mapFactory) {
        return Splitter.of(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                keyToKeyGroup, mapFactory, (innerMap, key) -> {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    final Map<K, V> castInnerMap = (Map<K, V>) innerMap.get(key);
                    return castInnerMap;
                },
                Map::put
        );
    }

}
```

Or to Gson `JsonElement`, `JsonObject` in particular:

```java
final class JsonElementSplitters {

    private JsonElementSplitters() {
    }

    static <V> Splitter<Map.Entry<String, V>, JsonObject, String, V> of(final Function<? super String, ? extends String[]> keyToKeyGroup) {
        return of(keyToKeyGroup, JsonElementSplitters::simpleObjectToSimpleJsonElement);
    }

    static <V> Splitter<Map.Entry<String, V>, JsonObject, String, V> of(final Function<? super String, ? extends String[]> keyToKeyGroup,
            final Gson gson) {
        return of(keyToKeyGroup, gson::toJsonTree);
    }

    static <V> Splitter<Map.Entry<String, V>, JsonObject, String, V> of(final Function<? super String, ? extends String[]> keyToKeyGroup,
            final Function<? super V, ? extends JsonElement> valueToJsonElement) {
        return Splitter.of(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue, keyToKeyGroup,
                JsonObject::new,
                (innerJsonObject, key) -> {
                    final JsonElement jsonElement = innerJsonObject.get(key);
                    return jsonElement != null ? jsonElement.getAsJsonObject() : null;
                },
                (jsonObject, property, value) -> jsonObject.add(property, valueToJsonElement.apply(value))
        );
    }

    // In simple cases we can do a primitive box value to a simple JSON value   
    private static JsonElement simpleObjectToSimpleJsonElement(final Object o) {
        if ( o == null ) {
            return JsonNull.INSTANCE;
        }
        if ( o instanceof JsonElement ) {
            return (JsonElement) o;
        }
        if ( o instanceof Boolean ) {
            return new JsonPrimitive((Boolean) o);
        }
        if ( o instanceof Number ) {
            return new JsonPrimitive((Number) o);
        }
        if ( o instanceof String ) {
            return new JsonPrimitive((String) o);
        }
        if ( o instanceof Character ) {
            return new JsonPrimitive((Character) o);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot convert " + o.getClass());
    }

}
```

Example of use:

```java
private static final Pattern dotPattern = Pattern.compile("\\.");

public static void main(final String... args) {
    final Map<String, Object> map = ImmutableMap.of("stackoverflow.questions.value", "value");
    final Splitter<Map.Entry<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>, String, Object> toMapSplitter = MapSplitters.of(dotPattern::split);
    final Splitter<Map.Entry<String, Object>, JsonObject, String, Object> toJsonObjectSplitter = JsonElementSplitters.of(dotPattern::split);
    // A simple to-inner-maps split example
    System.out.println(Split.split(map.entrySet(), toMapSplitter));
    // A simple to-nested-JSON-objects split example
    System.out.println(Split.split(map.entrySet(), toJsonObjectSplitter));
    // Or even use it with Java 8 Stream API
    System.out.println(
            map.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.getKey().toUpperCase(), e.getValue()))
                    .collect(Split.asCollector(toMapSplitter))
    );
}
```

Output:

```
{stackoverflow={questions={value=value}}}
{"stackoverflow":{"questions":{"value":"value"}}}
{STACKOVERFLOW={QUESTIONS={VALUE=value}}}
```

I'm not sure if any of built-in Java 8 `Collector`s can do this, but it looks something like a grouping collector.

Comment: Can you share this code in compilable classes, I can not build this in Androidstudio.